Negative values of the nuclear-nuclear (ion-ion) interaction energies DFT
I have observed that the output energy decomposition after a DFT calculation gives a negative value of the nuclear-nuclear (Ion-ion) interaction energy with ELK and SIESTA.
Elk Energies (Vanadium) :
Energies (Hartree):
 Fermi                       :     0.319795182346    
 sum of eigenvalues          :     -552.981504265    
 electron kinetic            :      959.189455328    
 core electron kinetic       :      875.841779129    
 Coulomb                     :     -1863.09399089    
 Coulomb potential           :     -1453.29669100    
 nuclear-nuclear             :     -131.017932273    
 electron-nuclear            :     -2010.85542624    
 Hartree                     :      278.779367618    
 Madelung                    :     -1136.44564539    
 xc potential                :     -58.8742685918    
 exchange                    :     -44.3894852379    
 correlation                 :     -1.02807046029    
 electron entropic           :    -0.619814949166E-04
 total energy                :     -949.322153244 

SIESTA (Vanadium) :
siesta: Final energy (eV):
siesta:  Band Struct. =     -40.754004
siesta:       Kinetic =     256.006987
siesta:       Hartree =       8.921362
siesta:         Edftu =       0.000000
siesta:       Eso     =       0.000000
siesta:    Ext. field =       0.000000
siesta:         Exch. =     -43.942268
siesta:         Corr. =      -5.400397
siesta:     Bulk bias =       0.000000
siesta:   Exch.-corr. =     -49.342665
siesta:  Ion-electron =    -250.546193
siesta:       Ion-ion =    -131.764090
siesta:       Ekinion =       0.000000
siesta: D3 dispersion =       0.000000
siesta:         Total =    -166.724600
siesta:         Fermi =      -6.651810

I don't know how they're calculated, but I guess, they're obtained by a classical formula totally dissociated from the quantum treatment of the electronic part. The interaction of two nuclei is supposed to lead to a positive interaction energy, why are they negative and if possible what are the expressions used for the calculation.
